# Read, edit, and save existing XML file with REXML

Tags: ruby, xml

Im' a beginner with Ruby and I made a little code to learn how to read/update XML in Ruby with REXML :

Here's my code :

```
# encoding: utf-8

# Programme used to store information about the state of mind of the user at different times.
# The user can later review all of his "state of mind" with the date he wrote it
require "rexml/document"
include REXML

$doc = Document.new File.new("som.xml")

def reads_old_som
  $doc.elements.each("StatesOfMind/StateOfMind") do |e|
    puts e.elements["Date"].text 
    puts e.elements["Content"].text
    puts ""
  end
end

puts "Describe your state of mind now ! (This must be between 10 and 25 words)"
content = gets.chomp
date_time = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

until content.split.length.between?(10,25)
  puts "It must be between 10 & 25 words, dude !"
  puts "Rewrite me this !"
  content = gets.chomp   
  date_time = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
end

som = Element.new("StateOfMind")
som.add_element "Date"
som.elements["Date"].text = date_time
som.add_element "Content"
som.elements["Content"].text = content
$doc.root.add_element som
$doc.write("som.xml", 2)

puts "Ok great ! Your state of mind was saved. Would you like to read the state of mind you wrote in the past ? (Y/N)"
choice = gets.chomp.capitalize

until choice == "Y" || choice == "N"
  puts "Please answer with Y or N"
  choice = gets.chomp.capitalize
end

if choice == "Y"
  puts "Here's all the state of mind you recorded :"
  reads_old_som
end
```

Everything works well, except for the fact that the data I add aren't stored in the XML fact. Obviously, the problem comes from the $doc.write part, but I cannot figure how to fix this !

I searched on the internet, and cannot finds a way to make this works. I need your helps, guys !

Comment: Do you need to use REXML? If I may suggest, Nokogiri is generally easier and faster. There's nothing wrong with REXML per se; most Rubyists (I think) now prefer Nokogiri however.

Comment: Does `som.xml` have any content before you add to it?

Comment: Nokogiri seems to be better indeed, but I mostly code Ruby at work when I have free time, and cannot download gems due to the firewall policy. At home, I think I won't use REXML, bu I won't code at home before a long time :)

Comment: "cannot download gems due to the firewall policy": wow!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$doc.write("som.xml", 2)
```

With

```
$doc.write(File.open("som.xml","w"), 2) ## Must open File in "w" mode in order to write
```

**The below code would only work if `StatesOfMind` tag exists in som.xml**

```
def reads_old_som      
  $doc.elements.each("StatesOfMind/StateOfMind") do |e| 
    puts e.elements["Date"].text 
    puts e.elements["Content"].text
    puts ""
  end
end
```

**NOTE:**

`$doc = Document.new File.new("som.xml")` means that `som.xml` already exists else it will throw an error. 
As per OP comment `som.xml` isn't empty so I have updated the code accordingly.

---

**Input XML(som.xml): som.xml must have at the minimum root element "StatesOfMind"(Notice Plural) present**

```
<StatesOfMind>
<StatesOfMind>
```

---

**This is the exact Code**

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML

$doc = Document.new File.new("som.xml")

def reads_old_som
  $doc.elements.each("StatesOfMind/StateOfMind") do |e|
    puts e.elements["Date"].text 
    puts e.elements["Content"].text
    puts ""
  end
end

puts "Describe your state of mind now ! (This must be between 10 and 25 words)"
content = gets.chomp
date_time = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

until content.split.length.between?(10,25)
  puts "It must be between 10 & 25 words, dude !"
  puts "Rewrite me this !"
  content = gets.chomp   
  date_time = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
end

som = Element.new("StateOfMind")
som.add_element "Date"
som.elements["Date"].text = date_time
som.add_element "Content"
som.elements["Content"].text = content
$doc.root.add_element som

$doc.write(File.open("som.xml","w"), 2)


puts "Ok great ! Your state of mind was saved. Would you like to read the state of mind you wrote in the past ? (Y/N)"
choice = gets.chomp.capitalize

until choice == "Y" || choice == "N"
  puts "Please answer with Y or N"
  choice = gets.chomp.capitalize
end

if choice == "Y"
  puts "Here's all the state of mind you recorded :"
  reads_old_som
end
```

---

**Output XML(som.xml) generated on the first run**

```
<StatesOfMind>
  <StateOfMind>
    <Date>
       17/03/2014 16:30 
    </Date>
    <Content>
       Hi This is Kirti How are you doing Nice to meet you. 
    </Content>
  </StateOfMind>
<StatesOfMind>
```

---

**Output XML(som.xml) generated on the second run**

```
<StatesOfMind>
  <StateOfMind>
    <Date>
       17/03/2014 16:30 
    </Date>
    <Content>
       Hi This is Kirti How are you doing Nice to meet you. 
    </Content>
  </StateOfMind>
  <StateOfMind>
    <Date>
       17/03/2014 16:32 
    </Date>
    <Content>
       Hi This is John Doe Nice to meet you. I am doing great.
    </Content>
  </StateOfMind>
<StatesOfMind>
```

Comment: som.xml isn't empty, it will contain the state of mind the user already wrote. In fact, the xml file will be used like a database for storing all the state of mind !

Comment: Then share the content of `som.xml`

Comment: @T2o Please see my updated answer. This would work for an existing som.xml with root element as `StatesOfMind `

Comment: I changed my do.write part, and it doesn't work either ! I'm pretty sure it's easy to fix, but I can't figure how !

Comment: @T2o I have provided the input xml + code + output xml. Try it with exact same code. Everytime you execute the code one <StateOfMind> element would be added to the root element <StatesOfMind>(Notice plural)